# Get an element's outer width in Prototype.js

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

Does Prototype.js have a simple way of returning an element's outer width?

ie: width + left/right padding + left/right border.

Like jQuery's .outerWidth()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Element.Layout](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/Layout/) can help you in this regard, Here is a full [fiddle demonstrating the options](http://jsfiddle.net/epoch/eDqzg/1/)

**CODE FROM FIDDLE**

```
var layout = $('d1').getLayout();
console.log('My Width : ' + layout.get('width') + 'px');
console.log('My Full Width : ' + layout.get('border-box-width') + 'px');
```

​

Comment: Are you sure? As far as I can see that still involves adding the 5 properties together

Comment: oops. scratch that - missed those composite properties